# Why are Monte Carlo and TD learning presented as two different methods when they appear to a continuum of each other?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

**Question** Are Monte Carlo and TD learning methods just the same thing with a different number of reward samples used to construct the update target? If so is there a reason for them being presented as different methods?

Reading Barto and Sutton and I am having a hard time understanding why Monte Carlo and TD learning are taught as two separate paradigms/methods of reinforcement learning.

As noted by Sutton himself “there are many different ways to construct an update target.” (True Online TD, Van Seine, Sutton 2016 )  If I understand this correctly(a big if) the only difference between the Monte Carlo and TD learning is the number of state returns actually being used in the construction of an update target.

So in Monte Carlo learning I sample the rewards from entire episode prior to calculating the update target, whereas in TD learning I sample the actual reward for the first n states and then rely on estimates of the remaining states to construct the update target.  (See Barto Sutton p.287)

I find this a little bit like teaching someone how to count, but instead of teaching “counting” as one idea, it is presented as though counting to ten is the Monaco Counting method but counting up to nine numbers is called the TD Counting Method.

To the novice it seems to add an additional layer of complexity, nomenclature and confusion.  Furthermore it doesn't seem that you can derive much qualitative information from the name of the method.  For example if I have an episodic task with a fixed number of n steps per episode.  Td(n-1) will yield results much more similar to the Monte Carlo method than say TD(1).

If anyone could point out what I am missing it would be very much appreciated.  Thank You.

Comment: I'm guessing you're in chapter 6 and the first few sentences of chapter 7 should be what you're looking for ;).

Comment: thanks.  I saw that but it still doesn't explain why one continuous concept is taught  as two discrete/distinct methodologies.

Comment: I see your point, but they are two distinct approaches and can be generalized using n-step TD methods in which case they become the extreme poles of a continuum.